# How to find the quantile, if the function $H$ is continuous CDF?

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution, quantiles

Let we define $H(\theta)= 1- \sum^{y}_{k=0} {n\choose k}\theta^{k}(1-\theta)^{n-k} + \frac{1}{2}{n\choose y}\theta^{y}(1-\theta)^{n-y}$. Thus, $H(\theta)$ is CDF.

My corresponding `r code` is given below.

```
theta <- seq(0,1, length = 100)
cd_theta <- function(x, p, n){
1 - pbinom (x, size = n, prob = p) + 1/2*dbinom(x, size = n, prob = p)
}
mytheta <- cd_theta(5, theta, 10)
```

I graphed $H(\theta)$ as follows.

[image]

My question is how to find the quantile function for given $\alpha \in (0,1)$, that is $H^{-1}(1-\alpha)$ or $H^{-1}(\alpha)$?

Comment: Could you please state more specifically what "finding" would amount to?  Would it be a closed formula (not possible except for special $y$), an algorithm, a numerical procedure, an approximation, or something else?

Comment: @whuber I have attached the graph $H(\theta)$ above. I am interested to find the quantile function for the cdf $H(\theta)$. Let say, when $\alpha = 0.05)$, I want to find the  $H^{-1}(0.05)$. Simply saying, are there any ways to find the inverse function of $H(\theta)$? Thanks.

Comment: Of course there are, as I mentioned in my comment.  What I'm trying to find out is *which* way do you need?  Some serve some purposes and some serve other purposes.

Comment: @whuber I am looking to solve via an algorithm or an numerical procedure.

Comment: @whuber But I am happy to see how other methods work and how they work. There is an another question just emerged, the density of $H(\theta)$ is, lets denote it as $h(\theta)$. Am I able to find the density by taking the first derivative w.r.t $\theta$, $h(\theta) = \dfrac{dH(\theta}{d\theta}$. Is it right?